# how to create a rotateY animation via jQuery and css 3

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create an intro page, like what is in this site via jQuery and CSS 3:
**[milaadesign.com](http://www.milaadesign.com/)**.
but I do not know how to implement it.

I know that I must some  element, that when mouseover event occurred for those I must to rotate it and show an image inside that.

I guess that I must use [**RotateY() transform CSS 3**](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp) and jQuery to animate it.

What is your idea for that this, and  do you know a jQuery plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS3 transitions and transforms you can achieve the desired effect. Something like this would do the trick:

```
<style>
#barContainer div
{
    height:300px;
    width:20px;

    background:#CCC;
    float:left;

    margin:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#barContainer div:hover
{
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);
    margin-top:15px;
}

#barContainer #bar1:hover
{
    background:#FF0000;
}

#barContainer #bar2:hover
{
    background: #00FF00;
}

#barContainer #bar3:hover
{
    background: #0000FF;
}
</style>

<div id='barContainer'>
    <div id='bar1'></div>
    <div id='bar2'></div>
    <div id='bar3'></div>
</div>
```

It'll only work on browsers that support CSS3 though.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ it does everything you need.

Here is a code sample:

```
$('.box').transition({
    perspective: '100px',
    rotateY: '180deg'
});
```

Should be pretty easy to customize to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [imagecube](http://jquery.com/plugins/project/imageCube) plugin .

Take a look :
http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the following that will help you to start.

**Plugin: More closely match your requirements** http://dev.jonraasch.com/quickflip/examples/

http://webmuch.com/image-flip-using-jquery/

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp